# Can these typescript functions be cleaned up or simplified?

Tags: typescript

I have these two functions:

```
import { handler } from '../lib/handler-lib'
import { APIGatewayEvent, Context } from 'aws-lambda'

export const producer = handler(async (
  _event: APIGatewayEvent,
  _context: Context
): Promise<object> => {
  return {
    some: 'data result'
  }
})
```

```
import {
  APIGatewayEvent,
  APIGatewayProxyResult,
  Context
} from 'aws-lambda'

export const handler = (lambda: Function): object => {
  return async (
    event: APIGatewayEvent,
    context: Context
  ): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
    let body: object
    let statusCode: number

    try {
      body = await lambda(event, context)
      statusCode = 200
    } catch (e) {
      body = { error: e.message }
      statusCode = 500
    }

    return {
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
      statusCode
    }
  }
}
```

Can this be simplified at all?

Both functions are defining the types for `event` and `context`, it would be great if just the second function did that so all callers could get the type declarations for free.

Should the arguments of `lambda: Function` be defined?

Comment: Yes, generally you will rarely if ever want to use type object or type Function, e.g. don't do `Promise<object>` or this `l(lambda: Function): object`. Those don't do what you might think they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would define the `lambda` function more clearer with input and output values.

`lambda: (e: APIGatewayEvent, ctx: Context) => Promise<any>`

Also you could make your code more concise by simply returning without creating temp variables:

```
import {
  APIGatewayEvent,
  APIGatewayProxyResult,
  Context
} from 'aws-lambda'

export const handler = (lambda: (e: APIGatewayEvent, ctx: Context) => Promise<any>): object => {
  return async (
    event: APIGatewayEvent,
    context: Context
  ): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
    try {
      return {
          body: JSON.stringify(await lambda(event, context)),
          statusCode: 200
      } 
    } catch (e) {
         return {
          body: JSON.stringify({ error: e.message }),
          statusCode: 500
      } 
    }
  }
}
```